# Spring Security OAuth2 - Custom Authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We need to expose a REST endpoint to the outside world to be called by an external service which we don't control. The people responsible for this external service seem to be security experts (**not**), and so instead of using at the very least HTTP Basic Auth or any other real authentication mechanism, they authenticate themselves using a fixed secret. It goes like this:

```
GET /endpoint?secret=WE_ARE_THE_TRUE_GUYS
```

As we're already using `spring-security-oauth2`, we'd like to integrate this authentication flow with our existing flow so that we can specify rules for this endpoint the same way we do for every other enpoint on our `ResourceServer`, get the same error handling behaviour and etc. How shall we go about implementing a custom authentication filter - or whatever it may be - that will grab the `secret` parameter from the query string, transform it into some kind of "client credentials" for a pre-configured client on the `AuthorizationServer` and integrate seamlessly with the rest of the OAuth2 flow?

Answer (score 2):

If you can transform "WE_ARE_THE_TRUE_GUYS" into a valid `OAuth2Authentication` then all you need is an authentication filter that does that (and sticks it in the `SecurityContext`). Then the downstream filters and handlers will behave just as if it was a real OAuth2 authentication. If I were you I would put some very tight conditions in that filter to match the request to one that is on the allowed resources from this highly unusual and not very secure authentication channel.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Do you have any suggestion on how to make that transformation (I want to identify them as an OAuth client, so no user authentication). And where in the Spring Security filter chain would I place this filter?

Comment: You can create an `OAuth2Authentication` from it's public constructor. Nothing fancy there. And your `Filter` needs to go before the resource server filter (which is normally before the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`  - see `org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer.configure(HttpSecurity)`).

Comment: Thinking about a slightly different approach, how can I call `TokenEndpoint` manually so as to exchange client ID and credentials for an access token (my idea is to stick it to the request headers on a filter that executes before everything else).

Comment: Isn't it the `TokenGranter` you want to call manually? You can exchange client details for a token using a `ClientCredentialsTokenGranter`.